# Is it safe to save the user's profile picture URL?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Can I just save the URL of the picture and use this URL every time I need to show the user's picture? or could this URL expire at some point at the future and therefore it's better if I save the image?

Comment: My undestanding is that the url is for the current picture. But once they change their profile picture, then the URL will change.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you use this format, you will always get the current user's public photo.

> http://graph.facebook.com/[userid]/picture

So for getting facebook's founder's pic, use: http://graph.facebook.com/4/picture

So the user could change their photo a million times, and you would always get the most current one. (Although in the case of Zuck, I don't think he's changed that photo for years)

Comment: If you put the URL directly in your image's `src` tag, then the http request for that picture comes directly from your user's browser. This means that Facebook can handle checking for privacy/security constraints of the profile picture, so you don't have to do it yourself, and will serve up a generic face picture if the profile picture is supposed to be locked down.

Comment: this looks like a security risk as anyone with the url will be able to reconstruct it to view the user's facebook profile...

Comment: I would suggest filing your critic with facebook.  However I doubt they'll change anything since we all need the public picture to be publicly accessible. http://graph.facebook.com/4/picture

Comment: Just to add to this .. you can also make a call like:
http://graph.facebook.com/4/picture?type=large
.. to get a large picture.  type can be large, normal,small